# Angular 2 Valuechanges

Tags: angular2-forms

Since last few days I am trying to resolve the issue regrading `valueChanges` in Angular 2 but couldn't find it exactly what I am looking for.

Below is my scenario.

There are 10-11 form controls in form group in my component. (using reactive forms)

I have subscribe the `valueChanges` on the form group. For every `blur` of control, the method is calling which I have subscribed for.

Question: How can I prevent that method calling for those controls having a validators applied? I mean with validators, if controls status is INVALID then it should not call that method.

By using `emitEvent` it is not even changing the UI value which I don't want. I want let UI control have the updated value.

Thanks,
Dhimant

Comment: Can you please post a sample of your code?

Comment: ngOnInit() {

  this.myForm = this.fb.group({
        fname: [, { updateOn: 'blur' }],
        lname: [, { updateOn: 'blur' }],
        id: [, { validators: Validators.required , updateOn: 'blur' }]
  });
  
  
  this.myForm.valueChanges.subscribe( () => {      
          this.saveChanges();
        });
}

1st: Here for id if I put it blank in UI and leave the field then validation occurs but at the same time saveChanges is also being called whcih I don't want until validation clears in UI for id field. Is there anyway to prevent that method calling?

Comment: I have one solutions right now is:

1. I can subscribe each form control separately and pass some arguments to that function by which I can identify the id field has called that method and after that I can check that form control whether it is valid or not and will apply that condition inside that method.

Here the problem is if I would have 10-11 controls in my page then I have to write subscribe for each controls which led to incresing the number of lines of code.